# Changing opacity using jQuery doesn't work in Chrome or Safari without screen refresh

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, safari, opacity

I wish to show/hide content on click, and am setting the CSS opacity rather than using `toggle()` or `hide()` and `show()` as I wish to have the content still occupy space on the page.

Here is the problem page (click the wee button in the top right to hide/show content): http://indigobrazilianportuguese.com/about-us/

And the jQuery:

```
$('.close').toggle(function() {
    $(this).siblings('p').text('Show content');
    $('#container').css('opacity', 0);
    $('#footer-container').css('opacity', 0);
}, function() {
    $(this).siblings('p').text('Show image');
    $('#container').css('opacity', 1);
    $('#footer-container').css('opacity', 1);
});
```

Works ok in Firefox and Opera, but not Chrome or Safari.

In Chrome and Safari the screen needs to be refreshed for it to work (e.g. when I resize the browser window the content is shown/hidden) although on other pages on the site the same button works fine...

Also tried adding adding/removing classes to apply the CSS opacity changes with no luck.

Any tips? Open to using an alternative to CSS opacity. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to occupy space then use visibility:hidden

Do the addClass and removeClass but use visibility instead of opacity and see if you get what you want

see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp

Comment: Thank you Huangism! Especially for being so quick.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.close').toggle(function() {
    $(this).siblings('p').text('Show content');
    $('#container, #footer-container').css('visibility', 'hidden');
}, function() {
    $(this).siblings('p').text('Show image');
    $('#container, #footer-container').css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mathletics, but Huangism got there moments earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that whenever a browser, no matter which, have a painting problem, and you just **know** there's no wrong with your code (one give away would be that the expected result show up in all the other browsers): Then simply do a **read** of this property and you should be fine. The read forces the faulty browser to "pay attention". Like so:

```
var never_mind_me = $(elem).css('opacity');
```

And then just throw away that value (thus you shouldn't even need to store the value in a variable, did so in my example for the sake of readability). It should do the trick. And of course, make sure to put that read in the right place (!important). Here's a more fuller example:

```
$('#myDiv').css('opacity', 0.5);
$('#myButton').on('click', function () {
    $('#myDiv').animate({opacity: 1}, {duration: 1000, complete: function () {
        // Oh no, we figured one or another
        // browser didn't finish his painting job.
        // The sorcery should be applied here:
        $(this).css('opacity');
        }});
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is known issue about Opacity in Chrome.

Do not use "Opacity" to hide elements – use "Visibility"

In your case in shouldn't be like this:

```
$('.close').toggle(function() {
    $(this).siblings('p').text('Show content');
    $('#container').css('opacity', 0);
    $('#footer-container').css('opacity', 0);
}, function() {
    $(this).siblings('p').text('Show image');
    $('#container').css('opacity', 1);
    $('#footer-container').css('opacity', 1);
});
```

But should be like THIS:

```
$('.close').toggle(function() {
    $(this).siblings('p').text('Show content');
    $('#container').css('opacity', 0);
    $('#footer-container').css('visibility', 'hidden');
}, function() {
    $(this).siblings('p').text('Show image');
    $('#container').css('opacity', 1);
    $('#footer-container').css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

Hope it will help somebody!